# doing bulk insert in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am trying to do bulk insert in Couchbase but it is not working. Below is the query snippet what I have tried :-

```
INSERT INTO `sk_status` (KEY,VALUE) VALUES ("key1",{"type":"statusName", "name":"NEW"} "key2",{"type":"count","name":10}) RETURNING *;
```

If I enter only 1 key i.e. key1 then it is working fine, the moment I add key2 then it gives me an error which I have mentioned below :-

Error

```
[
  {
    "code": 3000,
    "msg": "syntax error - at \"key2\"",
    "query": "INSERT INTO `sk_status` (KEY,VALUE) VALUES (\"key1\",{\"type\":\"statusName\", \"name\":\"NEW\"} \"key2\",{\"type\":\"count\",\"name\":10}) RETURNING *;"
  }
]
```

Any help/leads will be really much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Check out example 15, performing bulk inserts - https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/insert.html

You just need to make a slight syntax adjustment and use `VALUES` for each document. Here is an example:

```
INSERT INTO `travel-sample`.inventory.airline (KEY,VALUE)
VALUES ( "airline_4444",
    { "callsign": "MY-AIR",
      "country": "United States",
      "iata": "Z1",
      "icao": "AQZ",
      "name": "80-My Air",
      "id": "4444",
      "type": "airline"} ),
VALUES ( "airline_4445",
    { "callsign": "AIR-X",
      "country": "United States",
      "iata": "X1",
      "icao": "ARX",
      "name": "10-AirX",
      "id": "4445",
      "type": "airline"} )
RETURNING *;
```